# Extract names of objects from list

Tags: r

I have a list of objects. How do I grab the name of just one object from the list?  As in:

```
LIST <- list(A=1:5, B=1:10)
LIST$A
some.way.cool.function(LIST$A)  #function I hope exists
"A"   #yay! it has returned what I want
```

names(LIST) is not correct because it returns "A" and "B".

Just for context I am plotting a series of data frames that are stored in a list.  As I come to each data.frame I want to include the name of the data.frame as the title.  So an answer of names(LIST)[1] is not correct either.

**EDIT: I added code for more context to the problem**

```
x <- c("yes", "no", "maybe", "no", "no", "yes")
y <- c("red", "blue", "green", "green", "orange")
list.xy <- list(x=x, y=y)

WORD.C <- function(WORDS){
require(wordcloud)

L2 <- lapply(WORDS, function(x) as.data.frame(table(x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

    FUN <- function(X){
        windows() 
        wordcloud(X[, 1], X[, 2], min.freq=1)
        mtext(as.character(names(X)), 3, padj=-4.5, col="red")  #what I'm trying that isn't working
    }
    lapply(L2, FUN)
}

WORD.C(list.xy)
```

If this works the names x and y will be in red at the top of both plots

Comment: But, but, but ... you never gave a name to the data.frame. How are we supposed to print something that doesn't exist?

Comment: @DWin true but when I wrap the vectors up into a table and dataframe it retains the original vector names in L2.  A `browser()` after L2 and and `names(L2)` reveals this `Browse[1]> names(L2)
[1] "x" "y"`

Comment: So did you want the column names or the name of the object?

Comment: @DWin Name of the object (dataframes called x and y).  Sorry if I was unclear in this.  This one was a bit squirrely to explain.  What Dason showed is correct.

Comment: both question and answer here are so cluttered in unnecessary details :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Making a small tweak to the inside function and using lapply on an index instead of the actual list itself gets this doing what you want

```
x <- c("yes", "no", "maybe", "no", "no", "yes")
y <- c("red", "blue", "green", "green", "orange")
list.xy <- list(x=x, y=y)

WORD.C <- function(WORDS){
  require(wordcloud)

  L2 <- lapply(WORDS, function(x) as.data.frame(table(x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

  # Takes a dataframe and the text you want to display
  FUN <- function(X, text){
    windows() 
    wordcloud(X[, 1], X[, 2], min.freq=1)
    mtext(text, 3, padj=-4.5, col="red")  #what I'm trying that isn't working
  }

  # Now creates the sequence 1,...,length(L2)
  # Loops over that and then create an anonymous function
  # to send in the information you want to use.
  lapply(seq_along(L2), function(i){FUN(L2[[i]], names(L2)[i])})

  # Since you asked about loops
  # you could use i in seq_along(L2) 
  # instead of 1:length(L2) if you wanted to
  #for(i in 1:length(L2)){
  #  FUN(L2[[i]], names(L2)[i])
  #}
}

WORD.C(list.xy)
```

Answer (score 114):

You can just use:

```
> names(LIST)
[1] "A" "B"
```

Obviously the names of the first element is just

```
> names(LIST)[1]
[1] "A"
```

Comment: I added more context for clarity but names(LIST)[1] does not work.

Comment: The obvious solution it to replace the `lapply` with a loop and you are done... I doubt there is any clean way out as with `lapply` your function does not know which index is processing.

Comment: I was afraid a loop was the answer.  I'm really bad with loops.  R is my only language so with out an apply solution I am lost or very disoriented.

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c(1, -4, 0, -3, -1, 1) 
names(x) <- c("yes", "no", "maybe", "no", "no", "yes")
y <- c(22, 88, 99, 200, 100)
names(y) <- c("red", "blue", "green", "green", "orange")
list.xy <- list(x=x, y=y)
print(nl <- names(list.xy)) # this is not what you want!
# they are all equivalent, but one may fit better for a particular case
names(list.xy[[1]]) 
names(list.xy[["x"]])
names(list.xy[[nl[1]]])
```