# How to show elements of a list

Tags: r, list

I've got a simple question and I'm sure you can solve it:

How can I show the elements of a list?

If I have a list LIST of (named) elements, how do I know which elements are within this list without typing in "LIST"?

There must be a simple command like str(LIST), but I can't find it...

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking. If you have a list called x, you can view it by typing x at the command prompt. Please try to clarify the question, perhaps with an example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [extract names of objects from list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048375/extract-names-of-objects-from-list)

Comment: I'm sorry for the unprecise question, but I couldn't say it any clearer. I was really only looking for "names" to see the elements of a list (if they are called "elements") and I thought I had already tried "names"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> names(my.list)
> lapply(my.list, class)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit perplexed on why you don't want to simply type the name of the complete list to look at it.  But anyway, you can do the following.

You can use `unlist` to view all of the elements in the list. Or `str` to view the structure of the list.

```
> ll <- list(a = 1:10, b = 2:8, c = letters[1:10])
> ll
$a
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$b
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

$c
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"

> unlist(ll)
  a1   a2   a3   a4   a5   a6   a7   a8   a9  a10   b1   b2   b3   b4 
 "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9" "10"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5" 
  b5   b6   b7   c1   c2   c3   c4   c5   c6   c7   c8   c9  c10 
 "6"  "7"  "8"  "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e"  "f"  "g"  "h"  "i"  "j" 

> str(ll)
List of 3
 $ a: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ b: int [1:7] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 $ c: chr [1:10] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I was really only looking for "names" to see the elements of a list :-)

Comment: No problem.  I took "how do I know which elements are within this list " literally.