# Using lapply over list of data.tables to assign list member name as variable

Tags: r, list, data.table, apply

I have a list of data.tables

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(27)
test <- list()
test$a <- data.table(x = rnorm(n = 10),
                     y = rnorm (n = 10))
test$b <- data.table(x = rnorm(n = 10),
                     y = rnorm (n = 10))
```

Each member of the list has a unique name

```
test
```

In preparation to append these multiple tables into a single 'long' format, I want to create a third column that is a variable which is the name of each member via a function (I will need to do this regularly).

Currently working (though incorrect) code:

```
lName.asVariable <- function(dataTableList) {
dataTableList <- lapply(X = dataTableList, FUN = function(x)(x[, Site :=names(dataTableList)]))
}

test <- lName.asVariable(test)
test
```

Which ouputs

```
$a
               x           y Site
 1:  1.907162564 -1.28512736    a
 2:  1.144876890  0.03482725    b
 3: -0.764530737  1.57029534    a
 4: -1.457432503  0.15801005    b
...
$b
              x          y Site
 1: -0.57488122 -0.1520452    a
 2: -1.15190000 -0.9589459    b
 3:  0.08706853  1.8582198    a
 4: -0.07018075 -1.5747647    b
...
```

though what I want is

```
$a
               x           y Site
 1:  1.907162564 -1.28512736    a
 2:  1.144876890  0.03482725    a
 3: -0.764530737  1.57029534    a
 4: -1.457432503  0.15801005    a
...
$b
              x          y Site
 1: -0.57488122 -0.1520452    b
 2: -1.15190000 -0.9589459    b
 3:  0.08706853  1.8582198    b
 4: -0.07018075 -1.5747647    b
...
```

After reading [extract names of objects from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048375/extract-names-of-objects-from-list) `seq_along` might be what I need, though the following code produces an error:

```
lName.asVariable <- function(dataTableList) {
    dataTableList <- lapply(X = seq_along(dataTableList), FUN = function(x)(x[, Site := names(dataTableList)]))
}

test <- lName.asVariable(test)
test
```

I'm not sharp enough though to work out how to package `seq_along` to refer to the `data.table`correctly. Is this even the right tactic?

Comment: Use `mapply` (or `Map`) passing the tables and the names: `Map(function(x,.y)(x[, Site :=.y]), test, names(test))`

Comment: If you consider to `rbind` the lists to a single dataframe, try `rbindlist(test, idcol=TRUE)` which will get the names of the list elements as a new `.id` column

Comment: @nicola - Thanks, that works pretty well, though I am confused about the use of `.y`, not just `y`

Comment: @akun - I'm afraid that performing this on the data above is giving me an error. `Error in rbindlist(test, idcol = TRUE) : unused argument (idcol = TRUE)` I had spotted rbindlist{data.table}, though the only documented arguments seem to be `use.names` and `fill`

Comment: @DaveRGP I am using the `devel` version.  I think this was introduced recently.  Here is the link if you would like to install the devel version https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you end goal is to combine them into a single `data.table`, then in the latest version (1.9.5+) you can do it all in one step:

```
rbindlist(test, idcol = 'Site')
#    Site            x           y
# 1:    a  1.907162564 -1.28512736
# 2:    a  1.144876890  0.03482725
# 3:    a -0.764530737  1.57029534
# 4:    a -1.457432503  0.15801005
# 5:    a -1.093468881 -0.74579947
# 6:    a  0.295241218 -1.06880297
# 7:    a  0.006885942 -1.62743793
# 8:    a  1.157410886 -1.06858164
# 9:    a  2.134637891 -0.02583971
#10:    a  0.237844613  0.31957639
#11:    b -0.574881218 -0.15204521
#12:    b -1.151900001 -0.95894585
#13:    b  0.087068535  1.85821984
#14:    b -0.070180754 -1.57476470
#15:    b -2.998304014 -0.39814797
#16:    b -1.223994910  0.96868503
#17:    b -0.997074773  0.67118912
#18:    b  0.335713896  0.67889104
#19:    b  1.295343743 -0.17396132
#20:    b  0.327759944  0.78902925
```

Comment: @akrun has mentioned this in the comments slightly more completely. The only caveat being that as we discovered you currently need the dev build to make this function.

Comment: @DaveRGP you mean the part above where I say 1.9.5+? :)

Comment: @DaveRGP without 1.9.5 you can use `lapply(1:length(test), function(i, tbls) if(nrow(tbls[[i]]) > 0) data.table(Site = names(tbls[i]), tbls[[i]]) else data.table(Site = character(), tbls[[i]]), test)`. If you want to have one data.table just wraps the result into `rbindlist`.

Answer (score 6):

`seq_along` produces a sequence of numbers from 1 to the length of your list. You can then use an intermediate indexing variable to refer to the list item and the `names` item:

```
lapply(seq_along(test), function(i) test[[i]][,Site:=names(test[i])])
[[1]]
               x           y Site
 1:  1.907162564 -1.28512736    a
 2:  1.144876890  0.03482725    a
 3: -0.764530737  1.57029534    a
 4: -1.457432503  0.15801005    a
 5: -1.093468881 -0.74579947    a
 6:  0.295241218 -1.06880297    a
 7:  0.006885942 -1.62743793    a
 8:  1.157410886 -1.06858164    a
 9:  2.134637891 -0.02583971    a
10:  0.237844613  0.31957639    a

[[2]]
              x          y Site
 1: -0.57488122 -0.1520452    b
 2: -1.15190000 -0.9589459    b
 3:  0.08706853  1.8582198    b
 4: -0.07018075 -1.5747647    b
 5: -2.99830401 -0.3981480    b
 6: -1.22399491  0.9686850    b
 7: -0.99707477  0.6711891    b
 8:  0.33571390  0.6788910    b
 9:  1.29534374 -0.1739613    b
10:  0.32775994  0.7890292    b
```

Note that the output of lapply loses the names so you would have to reinstate them manually.

Comment: I could be wrong since I'm not used to `data.table`, but using brackets `[]` in the assignment maintains the names i.e. `test[] <- lapply(seq_along(test), function(i) test[[i]][,Site:=names(test[i])])`, so no need to reinstate them manually this way.

Comment: The same thing in a for loop would be better, I think. I'm guessing `lapply` produces a copy of the data (since it has a return value). `for(i in seq_along(test){test[[i]][,Site:=names(test[i])]}`

Comment: @PeterDee Yes, actually due to the way data.table works, the original variable gets modified without assignment and you can ignore the lapply output

Comment: @Frank Yes, I think you might be right. `lapply` and family are useful for performing operations without modifying the original data without explicit assignment, but data.table uses a different paradigm.

Comment: This is really great stuff, thanks to all. @Frank - you're right, though I think you need an extra `)` near the middle e.g. `for(i in seq_along(test)){test[[i]][,Site:=names(test[i])]}`

Comment: Also, @Frank, when putting your `for` in the context of a function: `lName.asVariable <- function(dataTableList) {
    for(i in seq_along(dataTableList)){dataTableList[[i]][,Site:=names(dataTableList[i])]}
}` the output becomes `NULL`?

Comment: @DaveRGP data.table modifies in-place, so you don't assign separately.

Comment: @James I'm sorry, not sure I understand? The question requires making a function, hence my attempt to insert the for loop into a named function.

Comment: @DaveRGP You would need to `return` the list after the loop, but the original list may already have been modified in the global workspace anyway. `data.table` modifies data in-place rather than makes copies.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this way works to you. But if you want the result, the below is easy way I believe,

```
 library(data.table)

set.seed(27)
test <- list()
test$a <- data.table(x = rnorm(n = 10),
                     y = rnorm (n = 10))
test$b <- data.table(x = rnorm(n = 10),
                     y = rnorm (n = 10))
test
test$a$Site <- "a"
test$b$Site <- "b"
test

$a
               x           y Site
 1:  1.907162564 -1.28512736    a
 2:  1.144876890  0.03482725    a
 3: -0.764530737  1.57029534    a
 4: -1.457432503  0.15801005    a
 5: -1.093468881 -0.74579947    a
 6:  0.295241218 -1.06880297    a
 7:  0.006885942 -1.62743793    a
 8:  1.157410886 -1.06858164    a
 9:  2.134637891 -0.02583971    a
10:  0.237844613  0.31957639    a

$b
              x          y Site
 1: -0.57488122 -0.1520452    b
 2: -1.15190000 -0.9589459    b
 3:  0.08706853  1.8582198    b
 4: -0.07018075 -1.5747647    b
 5: -2.99830401 -0.3981480    b
 6: -1.22399491  0.9686850    b
 7: -0.99707477  0.6711891    b
 8:  0.33571390  0.6788910    b
 9:  1.29534374 -0.1739613    b
10:  0.32775994  0.7890292    b
```

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but if I read this right you are manually specifying a and b? I need to be able to generate a and b programatically. Sometimes I might run it from a to z, or even 100 plus files :)