# How to get the labels of items in an R list

Tags: r

I have an object of type "Large list" and I want to get a list of the labels that follow the dollar signs below. How do I do that?

```
str(example_list)
List of 360
$ b32ad9c4fcbdd1f812                : chr [1:2201] "sd" "ssd" "dgaAL" "dE6" ...
$ 6ba9eb1aa59226b8                : chr [1:2320] "83r" "iTY" "dkeM" "4Kl" ...
$ e1680cf14ebc88bbd521                : chr [1:2687] "62V" "dAe" "ddv" "dAL" ...
```

Comment: I realize this is a duplicate, but my searching on the site for a while with slightly different language did not turn up an answer. It seemed worthwhile to ask a question the way I would have phrased it so that a future users have more of a chance of finding it.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `names` function because each item in the larger list is itself a list with its own name.

So with one item:

```
names(example_list[1])
```

we get

```
[1]     "b32ad9c4fcbdd1f812"
```

Then with the list of lists

```
names(example_list)
```

we get

[1]     "b32ad9c4fcbdd1f812", "6ba9eb1aa59226b8", "e1680cf14ebc88bbd521"

from an answer to this question: [extract names of objects from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048375/extract-names-of-objects-from-list)